# Rails 3.0.10 AJAX issue, create.js.erb file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery

I'm new to web development so bear that in mind.

I'm creating my first app using Rails 3.0.10

I have a micropost form that I'm trying to implement AJAX into.

I have set up the controller correctly(I believe) and have added `:remote => true` to the micropost form.

```rb
Microposts Controller

def create
      @user = User.find(current_user.id)
      @micropost = current_user.microposts.build(params[:micropost])
      if @micropost.save
        flash[:success] = "Created micropost"
        respond_to do |format|
        format.html { redirect_to @user }
        format.js
      end
      else
        render 'users/show'
      end
    end
```

The problem is in the create.js.erb file, in views/microposts

As a test, if I put

```js
$("#microposts").html("<p>Hello world!</p>")
```

it works as expected.

Even if I embed ruby code into it with an instance variable, that works too.

But, if I put

```js
$("#microposts").html("<%= render @microposts %> ")
```

it does nothing.

In fact, as soon as I try any rails method, it does nothing.

These are my javascript files that are included:

```
/javascripts/jquery.js
/javascripts/jquery_ujs.js
/javascripts/jquery.min.js
/javascripts/application.js
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, I have been stumped for little while now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not loading @microposts (the collection) in the create action.

So, you need to either need to set it via something like:

```
@microposts = current_user.microposts
```

But there's really no need to do another DB call. I'd recommend just appending (or prepending) your #microposts element with the new item. Something like:

```
$("#microposts").prepend("<%= escape_javascript(render '_micrpost_item') %>");
```

And that partial should be able to use the @micropost object from the create action.

Comment: Thanks. I ended up changing it a bit but this pointed me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
$("#microposts").html("<%= escape_javascript(render @microposts) %> ");
```